# @joinTable oneToMany Relationship

Tags: hibernate, join

I have **two tables** as follows :

```
AFFILIATES
----------
affiliateId (String) (PK)

CONVERSION
-----------
conversionId (Integer) (PK)
purchaseId (Integer) (not null)

PURCHASE
---------
purchaseId (Integer) (PK)
associateId (String) (allow NULL)
```

---

**Entity Mapping** as follows :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AFFILIATES")
class Affiliate implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name= "affiliate_id")
    private String affiliateId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="affiliate", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Conversion> conversion;

    public String getAffiliateId() {
        return affiliateId;
    }

    public void setAffiliateId(String affiliateId) {
        this.affiliateId = affiliateId;
    }

    public Set<Conversion> getConversion() {
        return conversion;
    }

    public void setConversion(Set<Conversion> conversion) {
        this.conversion = conversion;
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name="CONVERSION")
class Conversion implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="conversion_id")
    private int conversionId;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Affiliate affiliate;

    public int getConversionId() {
        return conversionId;
    }

    public void setConversionId(int conversionId) {
        this.conversionId = conversionId;
    }

    public Affiliate getAffiliate() {
        return affiliate;
    }

    public void setAffiliate(Affiliate affiliate) {
        this.affiliate = affiliate;
    }

}
```

Now I want to **get** all the **conversions** for the given `affiliateId`

I have `PURCHASE` has two columns, one from `CONVERSION` and one from `AFFILIATES`

I have **tried** following **code** but its **not working**,

```
String hql = "from Affiliate as a where a.affiliateId = 'abc'";
            Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
            Affiliate a  = (Affiliate) q.uniqueResult();
            System.out.println(a);
            a.getConversion().size();
```

I don't know how to get all the conversions for `affiliateID` abc.

If you have any idea then please let me know .

Conversion should be fetched through Third table **PURCHASE**.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand you schema, purchase doesn't seems to be just a join table rather it's an entity on its own. So create an entity of Purchase and create an appropriate relation with associate entity. A typical join table at least has two foreign keys pointing to related tables. It might have a surrogate primary key or a composite primary key (created with the combination of both foreign keys). Since purchase has a primary key (most probably surrogate) and another column which is foreign key so better to model Purchase as an entity

Comment: hi
Yes you are right Purchase is an entity, but it is not related to my Project so I can not make it as Entity,
I need some other work around.
and that purchase is also generated through hbm.xml file, so basically it is not part of JPA.